# Is there any way to wait Bootstrap modal to be loaded before triggering an action?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

After I migrated my website to Bootstrap 4, the event `loaded.bs.modal` stopped working.

Is there any way in Bootstrap 4 where I can trigger an action after my Bootstrap modal is fully loaded?

Comment: What about `shown.bs.modal`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#TestModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
         var count = 0;
         setTimeout("checkDdlTeachersLoaded('" + period + "', '" + staffLastName + "', '" + count + "')",100);
     });
});

function checkDdlTeachersLoaded(period, staffLastName, count)
{
    if ($("#ddlTeachers option").length > 0 || count >= 100) {
        //loaded
    } else {
        count++;
        setTimeout("checkDdlTeachersLoaded('" + period + "', '" + staffLastName + "', '" + count + "')",100);
    }
}
```